# How can I access files of different users and retain permission restrictions in Linux using Node.JS?

Tags: linux, node.js

I'm trying to reimplement an existing server service in Node.JS. That service can be **compared** to a classic FTP server: authenticated users can read/create/modify files, but restricted to the permissions given to the matching system user name.

I'm pretty sure I can't have Node.JS run as root and switch users using `seteuid()` or alike since that would break concurrency.

Instead, can I let my Node.JS process run as ROOT and manually check permissions when accessing files? I'm thinking about some system call like "`could user X create a file in directory Y?`"

Otherwise, could I solve this by using user groups? Note that the service must be able to delete/modify a file created by the real system user, which may not set a special group just so that the service can access the file.

Answer (score 1):

Running node as root sounds dangerous, but I assume there aren't many options left for you. Most FTP servers run as root too, for the same reason. Though, it means you need to pay a severe attention to the security of the code you are going to run.

Now to the question:

You are asking whether you can reimplement the UNIX permissions control in node.js. Yes you can, but Should Not! It is almost 100% chance you will leave holes or miss edge cases Unix core has already taken care of.

Instead use the `process.setuid(id)` as you mentioned. It will not defeat concurrency, but you need to think of parallel concurrency rather than async now. That is an extra work, but will release you of an headache of reinventing the Unix security.

Alternatively, if all of the operations you want to carry on filesystem involve shell commands, then you can simply modify them to the following pattern:

```
runuser -l  userNameHere -c 'command'
```

Comment: Using `process.setuid()` forces me to 
lock the whole process during the file operation, which is not an option since the service will have to handle a few hundred operations per second caused by a few hundred long-living contemporary connections. I get your point about reimplementing the permissions wheel, but should there be a O/S function just for that, my problem would be solved (there isn't however, AFAIK).

Comment: You spawn a new process per user connecting, like in old good days.. :) FTP Servers do exactly that, I doubt there is a workaround.

Comment: That will be difficult since the protocol is UDP-based... :-/ Thanks anyway.

Comment: It might be worth to consider next architecture: separate your operations code from the server. Keep network code in async manner, do all the regular stuff as you would do. Then once you want to do "list directory as user A", send an async call to your operations module, which would extract a necessary process (process owned by user A) from the pool or spawn if there is isn't one. Do the operation, and once done, finish the async call. That actually is an interesting challenge you are having here :)

Comment: That would be a good idea. The problem is, that this is meant to be a distributed system with a number of processes on more than one server to handle the load. The whole thing is all about reading/writing lots of files (which in fact is data exchanged with data acquisition devices), meaning that adding another layer would be very inefficient. In that case I rather do some basic permissions checks myself... :-/